# Modify SQL Row to set back date

Tags: sql

I am currently running a PHP script that is grabbing data from Facebook and putting it into my SQL database.  I want to now be able to see what Facebook posts were posted within 2 hours of the data grab, and I realized that the NOW() command was making a time that was 4 hours ahead of the offset for the Facebook server.

This brings me to three questions:

1) Is there a way to do a select command where I can offset the date by 4 hours?

2) Is there a way to modify rows to offset the date by 4 hours?

3) Will these methods actually set the entire date back, so that if a date is, let's say at 1:00 today (March 13th), it will be modified to be 21:00 the day before (March 12th).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any place you use a date in SQL you can use the DATEADD function, in a select, in an insert and in a where

```
 DATEADD(hour,4,datevalue)
```

To go back just use a negative number

```
 DATEADD(hour,-4,datevalue)
```

So, this

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime = '2013-03-13 01:01:01.110';
SELECT DATEADD(hour, -4, @datetime);
```

returns this:

```
2013-03-12 21:01:01.110
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is there a way to do a select command where I can offset the date by 4 hours?

Yes, using `DATEADD`/`DATE_ADD`

> 2) Is there a way to modify rows to offset the date by 4 hours?

You shouldn't be modifying the data.

> 3) Will these methods actually set the entire date back, so that if a date is, let's say at 1:00 today (March 13th), it will be modified to be 21:00 the day before (March 12th).

If you're using the `DATEADD`/`DATE_ADD` function and your date is in a `date` type, then yes.

[SQL Server Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

[MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)